# clFFT: Calculating overlapped FFTs

Tags: c++, fft

I want to create a batch for clFFT to calculate 3 FFTs of 256 length, where the FFT input values overlap (FFT overlap processing)

- Input: a 1D array of 276 complex numbers
- Task: Calculate FFTs for [0..255], [10..265], [20..275]
- Output: 3x 256 FFTs = 768 values.

If I where to write a loop, it would look like this:

```
std::complex<float> *input;

for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
   calcFFT(input, input+256);
   input += 10;
}
```

IOW: The fft calculates 256 input values then advances 10 values and calculates the next 256 values.

How do I set up a clFFT plan, so that this happens in one call?

clfftSetPlanIn/OutStride specifies the distance between the individual values, so that is the wrong parameter.

It looks as if clfftSetPlanDistance might be what I need. Doc says:

> CLFFTAPI clfftStatus  clfftSetPlanDistance( clfftPlanHandle plHandle, size_t iDist, size_t oDist );
>
> Pitch is the distance between each discrete array object in an FFT array. This is only used
> *  for 'array' dimensions in clfftDim; see clfftSetPlanDimension (units are in terms of clfftPrecision)

which I find very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `clfftSetPlanDistance` is the right API to use. In the example I would have to use

```
cllSetPlanDistance(plan, 10, 256);
```

to calculate FFTs with a step of 10.

This will generate OpenCL code where the global offset of the first FFT index is calculated like this:

```
// Inside the generated   fft_fwd   OpenCL function
    iOffset = (batch/32)*10 + (batch%32)*8;
```

where `batch` is the batch number of the FFT to calculate.